# How to link to a static version of a file in GitHub?

Tags: url, github

If I want to reference specific line numbers on GitHub, I can do so by finding the file on GitHub, and selecting the line numbers on the left.

I get a URL such as this:

> https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L190-L199

The problem is that this reference has `/master/` in it, meaning that if the file ever changes, the lines it will highlight are probably not the ones that I intended to highlight. How can I get a static version of this file so that I can reference this exact code I'm referring to?

Answer (score 1):

### Quick solution by modifying the URL:

1. Scroll to the top of the page, and you'll see a SHA of the latest commit.

   [image]
2. Replace `master` in the URL with the SHA; `6d1ae2a` in this case:

   > https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6d1ae2a/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L190-L199

### Using only UI:

1. Scroll to the top of the page, and you'll see a SHA of the latest commit. Click the SHA ([6d1ae2a](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/6d1ae2a39c1b77240107854b0ae1a35800a8ba73) in this case).

   [image]
2. Click "Browse files" on the top right.

   [image]
3. Find the file again. Now instead of `master`, you'll see the SHA in the tree:

   [image]
4. Highlight the lines as you did before and copy the URL:

   > https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6d1ae2a39c1b77240107854b0ae1a35800a8ba73/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L190-L199